# Mercurial repo to git repo access

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there a easy way to access the files in the git repo from the mercurial repo?

I would like to validate the config files in the git repo during the run time.
For now, i just copied the file to my mercurial repo and that is working as expected.

But in future, the content in the config file present git repo might change.

Comment: Have you tried [hg git](https://hg-git.github.io/)?

Comment: My understanding is hg git will be useful  for the files in the hg repository and i can access them from local Git. Pleas correct me if it is wrong.  share some reference link as well.

Comment: @saranyadeviM - your understanding of hg-git is inversed, while Kevin's suggestion - corect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to add the Git repositories as subrepos to your Mercurial repository.

Another possibility is to integrate getting the Git repositories as part of your build.

It's a bit hard to go into more detail without knowing the specifics.